# Is there any deep connection between Hyperion (the sci-fi novel) and Hyperion (the poem)?

Tags: inspiration, john-keats, dan-simmons, hyperion-cantos

*Hyperion* is a sci-fi classic by Dan Simmons which takes its name from the poem by John Keats of the same name. The novel makes multiple references to the poem by Keats and actually Keats is even a character in the story and Hyperion also happens to be name of the planet where portion of the story takes place.

However, beside the above obvious use of the name and reference to the author of the poem is there 'deeper' philosophical connection between the two pieces of literature? Is there some deeper thematic connection there? Is the story of the poem somehow 'woven' into the story of the novel?

Comment: There is also a Hölderlin novel and a Longfellow novel with the same title. Food for more questions?

Comment: @Tsundoku was not even aware of that thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Was Dan Simmons' Hyperion Cantos based on the story beats of the same Keats poems?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/300/17)

Comment: @Randal'Thor actually yes thanks for posting the link